# How to extract all nested json objects where spesific key/value pair is present?

Tags: json, regex

I'm trying to extract all nested json objects that contains a spesific key/value pair using regex, but i can't wrap my head around what expression to use.

```
  {
    "id": 15,
    "modificationDate": "2017-03-13T15:14:56.35Z",
    "translations": [
      {
        "id": 29,
        "language": "en"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "language": "nb"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "modificationDate": "2017-03-13T15:14:49.453Z",
    "translations": [
      {
        "id": 33,
        "language": "en"
      },
      {
        "id": 34,
        "language": "nb"
      },
      {
        "id": 35,
        "language": "nn"
      },
      {
        "id": 36,
        "language": "se"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "modificationDate": "2017-03-13T15:15:14.157Z",
    "translations": [
      {
        "id": 37,
        "language": "en"
      },
      {
        "id": 39,
        "language": "nn"
      },
      {
        "id": 40,
        "language": "se"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So i want to extract all nested objects containing *"language": "se"* in an efficient way.

Comment: Please add your efforts. Which regular expressions did you try?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for regex. Parse the JSON, loop the object, and check for your required object keys. Which programming language are you using? It will help to provide a relevant duplicate to your question.

Comment: What language do you want to do this in? Add it as a tag to your post please.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is missing some core information like the programming language that you are using.

Another thing is, your JSON doesn't look correct, you have more than one object in that JSON.

I don't think you need regex for what you want, i would just do something like this (this is Javascript):

```
if (jsonObject.body) {
  for(let i = 0; i < jsonObject.body.translations.length; ++i) {
        if(jsonObject.body.translations[i].language == "se") {
        // Do what you want with the object, 
        // I just printed the id of the translation
        console.log(jsonObject.body.translations[i].id);
       }
   }
}
```